What is the proper way to index status history tables in Postgres
We are using PostgreSql and have multiple tables which are laid out approximately like this.

A table for some entity in our system

apple

id | created_at | updated_at | user_id


An enum table with allowed values

quality

value (pk) | comment
---------------
okay       | ...
rotten     | ...
pristine   | ...


A status history table which records the status of that entity over time

apple_quality

id | created_at | updated_at | quality (fk) | apple_id (fk) | valid_at


A view on the status history table which gives the current status for each thing

CREATE
OR REPLACE VIEW current_apple_quality AS
SELECT
  DISTINCT ON (apple_quality.apple_id) 
  apple_quality.id,
  apple_quality.created_at,
  apple_quality.updated_at,
  apple_quality.quality,
  apple_quality.apple_id,
  apple_quality.valid_at
FROM
  apple_quality
ORDER BY
  apple_quality.apple_id,
  apple_quality.valid_at DESC;


Indexes on

(in this example)

apple_quality.id
apple_quality.apple_id
apple_quality.apple_id, apple_quality.valid_at desc


We are running in to issues where queries are needing to make a sequential scan of one of these status tables and its quite a bit too slow.
We are trying to ask questions akin to
"for a specific user, how many apples do they have which are rotten"
And our queries end up with a query plan that looks like this.
              ->  Aggregate  (cost=37256.06..37256.08 rows=1 width=32)
                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.71..37256.06 rows=1 width=8)
                          Join Filter: (apple.id = __be_0_current_apple_quality.apple_id)
                          ->  Subquery Scan on __be_0_current_apple_quality  (cost=0.42..37240.95 rows=544 width=16)
                                Filter: (__be_0_current_apple_quality.quality = 'rotten'::text)
                                ->  Unique  (cost=0.42..35880.96 rows=108799 width=113)
                                      ->  Index Scan using apple_quality_apple_id_valid_at_idx on apple_quality  (cost=0.42..34762.56 rows=447358 width=113)

So what I am wondering is

Is there a better way to write the view which is more easily optimized?
Are there indexes I should be adding?
Is there anything else i can do to improve performance without denormalizing data?

This is a pattern we've used many places in our app, so I figure there might be some well known solutions/tradeoffs I don't have the experience to know about.
I can provide more information upon request.

Hi, and welcome to dba.se! You say enum table when I think you mean lookup table? There's an enum type but you're not using that AFAICS!

This is a duplicate of this Stackoverflow question, and since you refuse to answer my questions there, there is little that can be added here.
